# How to loop over a subset of columns in a data frame to create new variables

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have several data sets comprised of ~250 variables on between 350-600 farming households in different regions. The data are very messy and have presented numerous problems for analysis. I am new to R, so any help on the below would be greatly appreciated.

Originally, several of the columns contained multiple variables, e.g. an "Inputs" column containing **up to 4** separate inputs (Fertilisers, Herbicides, Pesticides, and Hybrid Seeds). I used the `spread()` function in `tidyr` to create 4 new variables (Input_1... Input_4). The resulting, new "Input" variables look like the following **simulated** data frame, wherein each row represents a single farm household:

```
Input_1 <- c("Fertilisers", "Fertilisers", "Fertilisers", "Fertilisers", NA)
Input_2 <- c("Hybrid_Seeds", "Hybrid_Seeds", "Pesticides", "Herbicides", NA) 
Input_3 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Pesticides", NA)
Input_4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Hybrid_Seeds", NA)

x <- data.frame(Input_1, Input_2, Input_3, Input_4)

x

      Input_1      Input_2    Input_3      Input_4
1 Fertilisers Hybrid_Seeds       <NA>         <NA>
2 Fertilisers Hybrid_Seeds       <NA>         <NA>
3 Fertilisers   Pesticides       <NA>         <NA>
4 Fertilisers   Herbicides Pesticides Hybrid_Seeds
5        <NA>         <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
```

What I hope to do is to loop through each of these newly generated "Input" columns, search for a matching Input (e.g. "Fertilisers" or "Pesticides") and feed the result in "Yes/No" format to new variables **for each of the 4 types of inputs** in the data set (Fertilisers, Pesticides, Herbicides, and Hybrid Seeds). In other words, the results from the loop on `x` above would generate the following columns for the newly created "Yes/No" variables:

```
Fertilisers <- c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
Herbicides <- c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")
Pesticides <- c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
Hybrid_Seeds <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")

x2 <- data.frame(Fertilisers, Herbicides, Pesticides, Hybrid_Seeds) 

x2

  Fertilisers Herbicides Pesticides Hybrid_Seeds
1         Yes         No         No          Yes
2         Yes         No         No          Yes
3         Yes         No        Yes           No
4         Yes        Yes        Yes          Yes
5          No         No         No           No
```

It may be easier to visualize what I would like when data frames `x` and `x2` are combined into one:

```
x3 <- data.frame(x, x2)

x3

      Input_1      Input_2    Input_3      Input_4 Fertilisers Herbicides
1 Fertilisers Hybrid_Seeds       <NA>         <NA>         Yes         No
2 Fertilisers Hybrid_Seeds       <NA>         <NA>         Yes         No
3 Fertilisers   Pesticides       <NA>         <NA>         Yes         No
4 Fertilisers   Herbicides Pesticides Hybrid_Seeds         Yes        Yes
5        <NA>         <NA>       <NA>         <NA>          No         No
  Pesticides Hybrid_Seeds
1         No          Yes
2         No          Yes
3        Yes           No
4        Yes          Yes
5         No           No
```

The 4 inputs follow a certain order, i.e. Fertilisers will always be the first (Input_1) if the household uses Fertilisers, Herbicides will be Input_2 if they use both Fertilisers AND Herbicides (if they use Fertilisers AND Pesticides but NOT Herbicides, then Pesticides will be Input_2, etc. If the household uses all 4 Inputs, they will appear in the following order (see row 4 above): Fertilisers, Herbicides, Pesticides, Hybrid_Seeds.

I have attempted to create `for` loops to loop over all 4 input variables, look for matching strings, and input a "Yes" in the associated new input variable (e.g. the new "Fertilisers" variable if a match for "Fertilisers" is found in any of the 4 existing "Input" variables), but I have not had much success.

It seems as though there is no `apply` family solution to this problem, but I would be happy to be corrected. Again, I am new to R and programming in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I do have (very limited) experience with `for` loops but this problem has proven to be overly complex for me and it is very critical that it is solved, as it is a major barrier in moving forward in my research.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
tbl <- table(row(x), as.character(unlist(x)))
```

It is better to leave it as a binary output instead of changing to 'Yes/No', but if we need to convert then

```
tbl[] <- c("No", "Yes")[tbl+1]
```

and this can be converted to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
#    Fertilisers Herbicides Hybrid_Seeds Pesticides
#1         Yes         No          Yes         No
#2         Yes         No          Yes         No
#3         Yes         No           No        Yes
#4         Yes        Yes          Yes        Yes
#5          No         No           No         No
```